# Comparing current row and next row in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to compare current row and next row and based on some comparison need to derive a column value. Currently approach I'm following is making two different record sets and then use rank function and then by joining rank functions I m able to achieve this. However, this seems to be tedious approach, is there a better way to achieve this. I m currently writing query something like below :

```
select 
< comparing columns from two record sets and deriving column value> 
              (
        select(<some complex logic>, rank from a) rcdset, 
    (select <some complex logic>, rank +1 from a) rcdset2 where rcdset.rnk = rcdset1.rnk (+)
```

And this query the current row needs to be compared with every other row in the table except the previous ones, how can I do this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite vague, but you can simply use `lead()`:

```
select a.*,
       lead(col) over (order by <ordering col>) as next_col_value
from a;
```

You can incorporate `case` logic for a comparison.

Comment: what does over and order by do?

Comment: it doesn't really make sense to me because im trying to compare the first row with every other row in the database

Answer (score 0):

Recursive subquery factoring clause aka CTE or WITH clause often can help in such cases, because oracle optimizer can decide to "materialize" your subquery and it allows to reduce extra io and calculations.

For example:

```sql
with hard_view as (
select ... 
from ...
)
select *
from hard_view v1,
     hard_view v2
where v1.rnk = v2.rnk+1
```

Comment: Does this compare a row with every other row?